# Binding DatagridHyperlinkColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a datagridHyperlink column but i'm having trouble to get the id of My Object which has been clicked.

I've tried :

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Nom" Width="170"
                         Binding="{Binding MyObject.Name}" >
   <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style>
        <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="Click" />
        <Setter Property="Hyperlink.Tag" Value="{Binding MyObject.Id}"/>
      </Style>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn >
```

and my function :

```
private void ClicJoueur(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hyperlink hp = (Hyperlink)e.OriginalSource;
    int id = (int)hp.Tag;
}
```

My idea was to set the tag property to the id of my object and be able to manage the event and to know the id of the object clicked.

But it doesn't work, Maybe because the Tag property isn't a dependency property ? The tag obtained is always 0.

How can I get the real id of my object with a better solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to rely on *Tag* property, you can get it via **`DataContext`** of sender object which will be **`TextBlock`** in your case.

```
private void ClicJoueur(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int id = (((TextBlock)sender).DataContext as ClassName).MyObject.Id;
}
```

*Replace *ClassName* with your underlying class name where MyObject property is declared.

Comment: Nice thank you !
I have another issue, I'd like to bind the property isEnabled from my object. I've done : 
<Setter Property="Hyperlink.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=MyObject, Converter={StaticResource ConverterClass}}" />

with a converter which always returns false, but my hyperlink is always enabled

Comment: Please raise separate question with details in there. So, that someone from community can help you out (no one read the comments for questions). Right now, I didn't get your question where have you put that and on what condition you want it to be disabled. Please raise separate question with all this details added in it.